# Find two patterns within a specific object in a text file

Tags: php, regex, pattern-matching, text-files

I'm trying to find two patterns in a text file with PHP.

Text file looks like this:

```
[transactionDetails] => wsTransactionDetail Object
    (
        [sharesAmount] => 
        [sharesNumber] => 
        [amount] => 33450
        [commerceCode] => 1234567890
        [buyOrder] => 123321
    )

[detailOutput] => wsTransactionDetailOutput Object
    (
        [authorizationCode] => 001122
        [paymentTypeCode] => VD
        [responseCode] => 0
        [sharesNumber] => 0
        [amount] => 33450
        [commerceCode] => 1234567890
        [buyOrder] => 123321
    )
```

And my PHP code looks like this:

```
$pattern1 = preg_quote("authorizationCode", '/');
$pattern2 = preg_quote("amount", '/');

$pattern = "/^.*($pattern1).*\$|($pattern2).*\$/m";

if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){
   echo "Founds:\n";
   echo implode("\n", $matches[0]);
}
```

It works well but I'm getting **[amount] => 33450** two times because "**amount**" is two times in text file.

I need to get "**amount**" and "**authorizationCode**" values **only inside in this part** of the text file:

```
[detailOutput] => wsTransactionDetailOutput Object
    (
        [authorizationCode] => 001122
        [paymentTypeCode] => VD
        [responseCode] => 0
        [sharesNumber] => 0
        [amount] => 33450
        [commerceCode] => 1234567890
        [buyOrder] => 123321
    )
```

Could someone help me please?? I'll be grateful.

I think my problem is in regular expression:

```
/^.*($pattern1).*\$|($pattern2).*\$/m
```

I should modify that to find only patters inside **[detailOutput] => wsTransactionDetailOutput Object(**

Thanks you!

Comment: Can you access the data as an object instead? And is the order of the fields always the same?

Comment: This will get you the values, but it currently depends on the order `^\h*\[detailOutput] => .*(?:\R(?!\h*\[authorizationCode]).*)*\R\h*(\[authorizationCode] => \d+)(?:\R(?!\h*\[amount]).*)*\R\h*(\[amount] => \d+)` https://regex101.com/r/HtF0KM/1/

Comment: Hi @Thefourthbird, thanks for your help! It works perfectly in your regex101 but not in my php code :( Do you see something wrong in preg_match_all() function? I just replaced your regex in $pattern variable. Thanks for all! :)

Comment: I have added an answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

You could use 2 capturing groups. First match the `[detailOutput]` part followed by matching all lines that do not start with `authorizationCode` and capture the values for authorizationCode and amount.

```
^\h*\[detailOutput] => .*(?:\R(?!\h*\[authorizationCode]).*)*\R\h*(\[authorizationCode] => \d+)(?:\R(?!\h*\[amount]).*)*\R\h*(\[amount] => \d+)
```

*Explanation*

- `^` Start of string
- `\h*\[detailOutput] => .*` Match `[detailOutput] =>`  followed by the rest of the line
- `(?:\R(?!\h*\[authorizationCode]).*)*` Repeat matching all lines that do not start with `[authorizationCode]`
- `\R\h*` Match a unicode newline sequence and 0+ horizontal whitespace chars
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\[authorizationCode] => \d+` Match `[authorizationCode] =>`  and 1+ digits
- `)` Close group
- `(?:\R(?!\h*\[amount]).*)*\R\h*` Match all lines that do not start with `[amount]`
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `\[amount] => \d+` Match `[amount] =>`  and 1+ digits
- `)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HtF0KM/1/) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/U8knt)

Example code

```
$contents = <<<DATA
[transactionDetails] => wsTransactionDetail Object
    (
        [sharesAmount] => 
        [sharesNumber] => 
        [amount] => 33450
        [commerceCode] => 1234567890
        [buyOrder] => 123321
    )

[detailOutput] => wsTransactionDetailOutput Object
    (
        [authorizationCode] => 001122
        [paymentTypeCode] => VD
        [responseCode] => 0
        [sharesNumber] => 0
        [amount] => 33450
        [commerceCode] => 1234567890
        [buyOrder] => 123321
    )
DATA;

$pattern = "~^\h*\[detailOutput] => .*(?:\R(?!\h*\[authorizationCode]).*)*\R\h*(\[authorizationCode] => \d+)(?:\R(?!\h*\[amount]).*)*\R\h*(\[amount] => \d+)~m";

if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0)){
    echo "Founds:\n";
    echo implode("\n", $matches[0]);
}
```

Output

```
[detailOutput] => wsTransactionDetailOutput Object
    (
        [authorizationCode] => 001122
        [paymentTypeCode] => VD
        [responseCode] => 0
        [sharesNumber] => 0
        [amount] => 33450
[authorizationCode] => 001122
[amount] => 33450
```